# Plot non-linear data points with line in R

Tags: r, plot, line

I simulate some data with R code and want to plot these data.

[image: 1]

scatter plot is no problem with code plot(SX,Quant),
but when I use plot(SX,Quant,type='l'), the result is

[image: 4]

I just want the line through every point.

I try different type of plot, also use ggplot2 to try to modification,
but has same result, plz help me to solve this problem.

Comment: sorry, this is my fist question, I don't know how to show the picture, so only has picture link.

Comment: you need to sort your data - or use geom_line in ggplot2. Much better to include code as text rather than an image - folk cannot copy paste an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort your data by the x-value of your plot:

```
F_inverse=function(x) log((exp(1)-1)*x+1)
U = runif(100)
SX = F_inverse(U)
Quant=rank(SX)/100
ord <- order(SX)
SX <- SX[ord]
Quant <- Quant[ord]
plot(SX,Quant, type="l")
```

Comment: It work! Thank you very much.